# lighting problem in eevee in low light

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

[image: model in low light conditions displays weird artifacts]

Hello, working on project that has to have low light, two sources max and lots of shadows.
tried upping the viewport and render sampling but no luck so far, the model is shaded smooth and semi-low poly. dont really know what to change, more lights? settings? also material on model is a simple 2 tone cartoon shader made with a coloramp

Comment: Hi, without having access to your Blend file, I have no idea. Please upload it to https://blend-exchange.com/. Do you mean the problem disappear with stronger lights ?